# Sql order of data

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, insertion-order

I have the following problem. On my server I have to maintain data in particular order (to by specific order of insertion). And it has to be stored in a file. I'm currently using SQLite to do this, but is it safe to assume that SQL db will keep the order of insertion, or should I use something else (in this case please give me a hint what to do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rows in a table are not stored in any particular order.  You can only guarantee order with an `order by` clause.

To order rows by insertion, you'd typically use an [autoincrement](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) column.  That assigns a higher values to rows that are inserted later.  You can then `order by autoinc_col` to retrieve rows in the order in which they were inserted.